# nuxt 3 I18n internationalization _ctx.$t is not a function

Tags: nuxt.js, internationalization, vue-i18n

// nuxt.config.js

```
   // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
   '@nuxtjs/axios',
   'nuxt-swiper',
   '@nuxtjs/i18n',
 ],
 i18n: {
   lazy: true,
   langDir: 'locales',
   strategy: 'prefix_and_default',
   locales: [
     { 
       code: 'en-US', 
       iso: 'en-US', 
       name: 'English(US)', 
       file: 'en-US.json' 
     },
     { 
       code: 'es-ES', 
       iso: 'es-ES', 
       name: 'Espanol', 
       file: 'es-ES.json' 
     }
   ],
   defaultLocale: 'en-US',
   // vueI18n: {
   //   fallbackLocale: 'en-US',
   // }
 },
```

//package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
    "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/fullpage.js": "^2.9.6",
    "nuxt": "^3.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/kit": "^3.7.4",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "fullpage.js": "^4.0.20",
    "gsap": "^3.12.2",
    "intl-tel-input": "^18.2.1",
    "isotope-layout": "^3.0.6",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "nuxt-swiper": "^1.2.2",
    "ohmyfetch": "^0.4.21",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "postcss-less": "^6.0.0",
    "smooth-scrollbar": "^8.8.4",
    "stylelint": "^16.1.0",
    "swiper": "^11.0.5",
    "vue": "^3.4.13",
    "vue-browser-geolocation": "^1.8.0",
    "vue-intl-tel-input": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-phone-number-input": "^1.1.7",
    "vue-tel-input": "^8.1.4"
  }
```

// locales/en-US.json

```
{
    "hello_text": "Hello",
    "products_text": "Products"
}
```

// locales/es-ES.json

```
{
    "hello_text": "สวัสดี",
    "products_text": "ผลิตภัณฑ์"
}
```

// component.vue

```
<p>{{ $t('products_text') }}</p>
```

I have installed the plugin as it's showing in my pacakge.json and config all the necessary configurations in nuxt.config.js still having this error can anyone help why this error is showing up ??